# Woocommerce add custom input field for product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**Woocommerce Add Custom Input Field for Product.**

I want to add `custom text fields` to the Product where a user can add values, say fields size where a user can enter the value like **10* 10** or whatever they was and same to be shown in order .

Please guide me how can this be done i can not find any setting for same in backend

Comment: can you show me where would you like to add exactly i mean frontend or backend , if possible send screenshot

Comment: thanks got working using wc-fields-factory

Comment: This sounds like [WooCommerce Product Addons](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok spending money, you are looking for this extension:

https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-custom-fields-product-addons/11332742